# Split column value into multiple columns in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I split column value into multiple column based on the length of the column.

```
SELECT COLUMNA FROM TABLE

COLUMNA
My Name is Erick.
```

I want to limit column length to 5 characters so it will divide the following string into 3 column.

```
COLUMNA   COLUMNB  COLUMNC
My Na     me is     Eric
```

If the string doesn't fit in 3 columns it should discard the rest of string.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substr()`:

```
select substr(columna, 1, 5) as columna,
       substr(columna, 6, 5) as columnb,
       substr(columna, 11, 5) as columnc
from t;
```